# Electron's WebView functions doesn't work

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

So when I create a `webview` element using JavaScript (`document.createElement`) all it's functions are `undefined`.
Shortly:

```js
let wv = document.createElement("webview");
wv.loadURL("https://google.com");
```

Returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: wv.loadURL is not a function
```

How do I fix it?

Also yes, I do have `webviewTag` enabled in main process' `webPerferences`.

Comment: Sounds like a dependency problem.

Comment: I don't think so. `WebView` is electron's built-in element.

Comment: And yet you spell it differently here in comments (case-sensitive maybe?)

Comment: I just use `WebView` to type it in comment, in code I obviously use `webview`. Auto completions anyway...

Comment: I didnt mean it in a snarky way, as I havent done any research. I just mentioned if case sensitivity mattered? What we do know is `wv.loadUrl` is failing. is `wv` null?

Comment: Nope. When I `console.log`, it returns element as regular.

Comment: ...And when I `console.log` those (`loadURL` etc.) functions it just returns `undefined`.